# How do I search for html tags in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to find all instances of `<script>` in my solution in Visual Studio 2010. Here are the steps I take:

1. Type CTRL+Shift+F
2. Type `<script` into the "Find what:" textbox
3. Click "Find All" button

I only get results where `<script>` is in a string (i.e. `var foo = "<script>do something</script>`, where `<script>` was the only html tag in a .cshtml file, or where `<script>` is in a comment (i.e. `//Close the <script> tag`).

I tried a Regular Expression search with `\<script\>` which yielded 0 results. I've had the same results searching for `<a>`. I haven't done an exhaustive test of the Visual Studio 2010 search with all html tags, but it seems to be equally broken for all html tags.

How can I find what I'm looking for in my source code?

Comment: Do you have things defined as `<script>` or are the all something like `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your script tags are defined like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Instead of this:

```
<script></script>
```

So try this out with Use Regular Expressions checked in the Find Options:

1. Hit CTRL+F
2. Go to "Find in files..."
3. use this expression:

> `\</*script[ ]*.*\>`
>   
>   It should find all of your opening and closing `<script>` tags. Be careful if you're trying to do a find and replace, though. When I ran it, I got some results from within a couple third party javascript files (including knockout).

I know it's not exactly the best regex syntax, but the Visual Studio find syntax is apparently different from the regular .NET regex.

Comment: Good call. Thanks for catching that.